# Is it possible to develop ASP.NET MVC with MS Visual C# 2008 Express Edition and IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, iis

Is it possible to develop ASP.NET MVC with MS Visual C# 2008 Express Edition and IIS?

The [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-21-cs.aspx) states that 'Visual Studio 2008 or Visual Web Developer 2008 Express' are required.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't develop an ASP.NET (MVC or otherwise) using Visual C# 2008 Express without a big kludge. C# Express is mainly for Windows applications.

What you *can* do is download and install Visual Web Developer 2008 Express. This edition is for ASP.NET developer (in C# or VB.NET). Unlike the Standard or Professional, with Express the functionality is split into 4 seperate packages - C# Express for C# desktop development, VB.NET Express for VB.NET desktop development, C++ Express for C++ desktop development, and Web Developer Express for any type of ASP.NET development. You can download and install all 4 of these on the same machine (they should even share the same copy of MSDN Express).

If you want it all in one IDE, you need to pay for Standard or Professional.

Oh, and just make sure you download the SP1 version of Web Developer 2008 Express, it's really annoying trying to install SP1 on the Express editions (or at least it is if you have some other versions of VS on the same machine), and you need SP1 to install MVC.

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for.  Thanks David :)

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible. I haven't really used the Express editions enough to know what is easier or more difficult in one edition or another but the Web Developer edition is also free.

Comment: Just to clarify:  Have you used MS Visual C# 2008 Express Edition?

Comment: Yes, I have. You can actually build ASP.NET applications with just a text editor and some web server, like Casini.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this is to get the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx). It installs everything you need to get going with web dev. Some have claimed that its vista only, but I was able to use it to install it on XP HOME on my asus netbook.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean regarding running ASP.NET MVC projects? To run it, you'd need a Web server rather than Visual Studio. For development, you can develop a class library in C# Express that will be used in an ASP.MVC app but project templates are only available for Web development product line (Visual Web Developer or full VS)

Update to reflect OP edit: To develop apps *effectively*, you'll need Visual Web Dev or VS. There's no point in not using VWD Express as it's free.

Comment: I want to develop, not just run MVC projects.  I have edited the question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I have installed some of the previews.  You just don't get MS Test.

Edit:  That was with VS Express Web Developer Edition, however.

Answer (score 0):

At least Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition SP1 requred. I think it's just enough for ASP.NET MVC development if you are not working in the team. There are a lot of great 3d-party testing frameworks - you are not constrained only to MS Test.